# Android + Estimote Beacons: get the closest one

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, estimote

I'm making an App that uses BLE Beacons. We are using Estimote beacons and their framework. I followed [this tutorial](http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-1-setting-up/) do add the detection in my App.

The detection happens successfully and I can get the list of beacons, using the code below:

```
this.beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
this.beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.BeaconRangingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(BeaconRegion beaconRegion, List<Beacon> list) {

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            MainActivity.this.updateClosestBeacon(list);
        }
        else {
            txtClosest.setText("No beacons detected");
        }
    }
});

this.beaconRegion = new BeaconRegion("monitored region",
        UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),
        null, null);


beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceReady() {
        beaconManager.startRanging(beaconRegion);
    }
});
```

The updateClosestBeacon function get's the beacon using these two functions:

```
private static Comparator<Beacon> COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Beacon>()
{
    // This is where the sorting happens.
    public int compare(Beacon o1, Beacon o2)
    {
    return o2.getRssi() - o1.getRssi();
    }
};


public Beacon getClosestBeacon(List<Beacon> list){

    if(list.isEmpty())
        return null;

    Collections.sort(list, COMPARATOR);

    return list.get(0);
}
```

I order the list of beacons by rssi and then get the first. This is not working properly. I looked into estimote forum for the answer and there I could not find it, just some links to videos showing the beacon detection.

Would you have some piece of code that could help me to process the list the beacons and get the closest one?

Thanks for any help

Comment: RSSI is an inaccurate, and some would say inappropriate method to determine relative distance.  RSSI is affected by many factors like obstacles, multi-path fading, antenna polarization, and cross-body shielding.  Instead, one could try looking at a _trend_, though it will not necessarily guarantee the ability to differentiate distance between two device distances.

Comment: @CzarMatt I'm not sure if I understood what is trend. Would you have a link with some example?

Comment: Does the `Comparator` code do anything? What do you mean by "is not working properly"?

Comment: From my experience with BLE Beacons I would recommend you to compare the **mean value** for multiple RSSI values instead of comparing a single value. In general the RSSI is not constant and therefore it happens sometimes that the closest Beacon hasn't got the highest RSSI value.